# load the content of html file into the div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, load

I am a beginner. The problem I am dealing with is probably very simple to solve ;) I am working on a web page where the text content is loaded from external html files into the div. This is done when a user clicks on a menu item.

This is my code html :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
          <div>
                      <ul>      
                          <li><a id="teachers" href="#" name="teachers" onclick="getdata()">
                            Teachers
                          </li> 
                        </ul>
          </div>

          <div id="page"  name="" >
            bla bla bla ...
          </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code ajax:

```
var _xhr;

function getdata(){

    _xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    _xhr.onreadystatechange=callback;
    _xhr.open("POST", "teachers.html", true);
    _xhr.send();

    function callback(){
        var _target = document.getElementById("page");
        _target.innerHTML=_xhr.responseText;
    }

}
```

I would like to load the html file (teachers.html) into the div (id="page") when I click on the link (Teachers)

Please could someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: javascript jsp or php. Google for it

Comment: Your code looks like it does that already. What's the problem? Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: What happened when you run your code? You declared the function "callback" inside the function getdata(). What happens if you move callback function before _xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you all, I will try what you told me

Comment: the same problem , my problem is my responseText is empty

Comment: Please take a look at this error :

 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/Projet/teachers.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///F:/Projet/teachers.html'.

Answer (score 0):

try changing POST to GET and see if that works.

Comment: are all of the html files in the same directory?

Comment: I have a suspicion that the request is being blocked by the browser . check the network tab on chrome developer tools and see if you get an error. Also try providing a full URL for this line :   _xhr.open("POST", "teachers.html", true);

Comment: Are you running this code on a server, if not this is a security issue you will come across when attempting to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

for this case i recommend to user jQuery Load function. its easy to use and fit your needs. you can find more in the following link: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Yes but I would like to use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty hard to know if you don't tell us what happened. I´ve figure out (maybe) a problem

Try Change your code to

```
function getdata(){

    function callback(){
        var _target = document.getElementById("page");
        _target.innerHTML=_xhr.responseText;
    }


    _xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    _xhr.onreadystatechange=callback;
    _xhr.open("POST", "teachers.html", true);
    _xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: the same problem , my problem is my responseText is empty

Comment: What browser are you using? In chrome, you can open the "developer tools" (ctrl+shif+i) and open the "network" tab. So, execute your code again and see if the browser is downloading the file. Just click on the file and select the tab "response". Take a look in the status code too. It should retrieve 200.

Comment: Please take a look at this error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/Projet/teachers.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///F:/Projet/teachers.html'.

Comment: Please, take a look at this document: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr. Your error is a security issue blocking by your browser. It thinks that a web page is trying to load a local resource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bringing the var _xhr; inside the function?

i tried the below.. it worked

```
function getdata(){
                var xmlhttp;
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("get","techers.html",false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                document.getElementById("page").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an ajax call?

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/